# Exception :com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am using the Jersey API for the web services. I am sending the multipart data from client to server. I am getting exception when web services start to execute.

```
@POST
@Path("uploadphoto")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String uploadNotices(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    String uploadedFileLocation = "d:/" + fileDetail.getFileName();
    // save it
    try {
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "no";
    }
    return "yes";
}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) throws Exception {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String com.homebulletin.resources.NoticeResources.uploadNotices(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String com.homebulletin.resources.NoticeResources.uploadNotices(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at parameter at index 1
  SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String com.homebulletin.resources.NoticeResources.uploadNotices(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), annotated with POST of resource, class com.homebulletin.resources.NoticeResources, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Jun 18, 2013 10:55:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 18, 2013 10:55:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Home Bulletin
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you have all the required libs in your project? using maven?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems your missing few jars in your project.Try adding these to your project:

> **jersey-multipart.jar**
>
> **mimepull.jar**

If you are using maven, you can add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Change the version of jar if you need

**Also make sure that the version of your jersey-multipart jar should be same as the version of jersey bundle jar**

Comment: I added the mimepull-1.3.jar and jersey-multipart-1.8.jar. But still getting exception.

Comment: Where have you added? Make sure those are available at run-time

Comment: SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String com.homebulletin.resources.NoticeResources.uploadNotices(java.io.InputStream) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String com.homebulletin.resources.NoticeResources.uploadNotices(java.io.InputStream), annotated with POST of resource, class com.homebulletin.resources.NoticeResources, is not recognized as valid resource method.
Jun 18, 2013 11:41:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

Comment: I added them in the WEb-INF -> lib folder of the project

Comment: @Android Also make sure that the version of your  jersey-multipart jar should be same as the version of jersey bundle jar

Comment: jersey-bundle-1.8.jar and jersey-multipart-1.8.jar & mimepull-1.3.jar & jersey-server-1.8.jar but still getting exception.

Comment: I put the jersey-bundle-1.14.jar &  jersey-multipart-1.14.jar but in java source code I am getting error "import com.sun.jersey.multipart can not resolved"

Comment: +1 thanks problem resolved it was problem of versions of jar files.

Comment: How can i save the photo on the server folder. Please share if you have any idea of this

Comment: @Android post a new question ;-)

Comment: What if I am not using MAVEN?

Comment: @JiajuShen you will have to download all required jars manually. In my pre-maven days, i used google and the following website to find jars: http://www.findjar.com/index.x

Answer (score 14):

Forgetting to add `@POST` or `@Get` on top of the method name will also cause this error

Comment: +1 In my case the reason for error was, I was using `@FormParam` in method which was listening to `@GET` method.

Comment: I lost couple of hours digging everything and i was this annotation.. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It faced me the same error because having same @Path annotations with the same path names( strings).

```
@Path('samepath')   /// samepath cause Jersey Error at run time.
/* Method 1*/

@Path('samepath')
/* Method 2 */
```

Comment: And what is your proposed solution to the problem? In what way does this answer the question?

Comment: @luk2302 I think he gave a suggestion about what may be wrong, I don't see what he could have explained more in this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

> com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException

occured when I had two `@GET` methods with the same path but different query params.

Also it may happen if you rename your controller class, do `mvn install` without `mvn clean` and put war file to `/webapps` folder.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen exactly the same error when using `@FormParam` (which expects `@POST`) with `@GET` parameters.

Hope it will help someone as it wasn't very intuitive to find out.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `web.xml` with this code:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>  org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem because I did not have no parameter constructor in my class

```
@Path("/deviceconfigs")
public class DeviceConfigInterface extends ComInterfaceGen<DeviceConfigApi> {
    public DeviceConfigInterface(Class<DeviceConfigApi> type) {
        super(DeviceConfigApi.class);
    }
}.
```

When I used no parameter constructor, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as I missed out to add a "Consumes" annotation for my POST method. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's to late. But updating it here for future references. 
Better check the  jar versions. 
I had the same issue. I was using the 1.16 version of jersey core and server, but this one i added with 1.18. It gave the same error. But then I realized and changed to 1.16 then worked fine.

It doesn't work with different versions.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple potential reasons therefore, just mentioning the most common ones

- you are lacking some JAR files
- you have multiple java methods with the same @Path annotation and the same HTTP methods (i.e. with different params or query params)
- you have a web service method with an invalid response or request param type (i.e. a annotation class as parameter class or other weird stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you specified @FormDataParam instead @QueryParam in GET method, in my case that was the problem.