# Missing dependency for method error for RESTful webservice with FileInputStream

Tags: rest, multifile-uploader

continuing on [Exception :com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161285/exception-com-sun-jersey-spi-inject-errorserrormessagesexception), which had the same Issue, I am not clear on what is the end Solution.

do we need mimepull.jar of same version as jersey-multipart.jar ?

I have below jars:

```
glassfish.jaxws.mimepull_1.1.0.0_1-3.jar

com.sun.jersey.multipart_1.0.0.0_1-9.jar
com.sun.jersey.core_1.0.0.0_1-9.jar
com.sun.jersey.client_1.0.0.0_1-9.jar
```

and

```
jersey-bundle_1.0.0.0_1-1-5-1.jar
```

my webservice method is like below:

```
@POST
@Path("createEntity")
@Consumes("*/*")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})   
public Response createEntity(SomeType entity, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream in,
                       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws Exception
```

Thanks
Debashish