# Errors$ErrorMessagesException when using Jersey in Java

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using Jersy to develeop REST webservices, this is my simple code:

```
@GET
@Path("/retrieveCustomerInformation/{jsonString}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String retrieveCustomerInformation(@PathParam("jsonString")JSONObject jsonObject) 
    throws Exception  {
      //Other codes here

    }
```

But when I ping the rest service url from browser, I am getting below exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
```

and the root cause is:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
```

Can someone guide me, what causes this error? I am finding difficult to understand this error message as it doesn't provide any useful information to debug.

This is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
            </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.test/param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using Jersey 1.8, JDK 1.7 and App is running on Tomcat 7.0. If required I can provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to be a duplicate and has probably been appropriately addressed. I too had the same issue some time ago. [Click here to see the accepted answer that resolved it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161285/exception-com-sun-jersey-spi-inject-errorserrormessagesexception)

And in case you're reluctant to follow the link, first of all, try adding **`jersey-multipart.jar`** and **`mimepull.jar`** to your project libraries... And if your project is a Maven project, add the following dependencies to your `pom.xml`. The `mimepull` dependency should ship along with it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Remember to ensure that the version of *`jersey-multipart`* that you use, is the same as the version of *`jersey`* that you're using in the project.**

Just in case the above solution doesn't resolve your issue, you may want to see **[here](https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/issue_dev_ing_restful_json)** for more useful tips too. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Check for clashing @Path annotations.
This will result with the same error. It's a weird error for communicating path issues, but you can easily test it by renaming the matching paths.

Example of cashing paths in the code below

Some class

```
@Path("/storage")
public class BookingRestService {

@GET
@Path("/bookings")
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

and another class

```
@Path("/storage")
public class StorageRestService {
```

By renaming any of the `@Path("/storage")` the problem is remediated.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency from the reference

[Jersey Application Deployment and Runtime Environments](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rest.portal</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rest.portal.HelloWord</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In Jersey 1.x only using the

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

In 2.x series use

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

And add necessary jersy jar files

1. asm-5.0.2.jar
2. jersey-common.jar
3. jersey-servlet-container-core.jar
4. jersey-servlet-container.jar
5. jersey-server.jar

Answer (score 0):

One more use-case, which causes the same exception, which broke my code.
If you were to write the resource like this:

```
public String getPOST(@QueryParam("type") Character type){}
```

the following data type, `Character`, will cause the exception.