# java using jersey framework

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am developing a website based on jersey and I got stuck.

This is my code and i am getting the error followed by the code.Please help me with this.

```
package com.youtube.rest.status;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//import jdbcdemo.DataSource.java;
//import jdbcdemo.DataSource;

import com.youtube.rest.dao1.Oracle308tube;

@Path("/v2/status")
public class V1_status {
    private static final String api_version="00.01.00";

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle(){
        return "<p>Java Web Service</p>";
    }

    @Path("/version")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnVersion(){
        return "<p>Version:</p>" + api_version;
    }
}
```

The error which I am getting is as follows:

```
Apr 09, 2015 7:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Jersey REST Service
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem not in your code.
Try adding `jersey-multipart.jar` and `mimepull.jar` to your project.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161285/exception-com-sun-jersey-spi-inject-errorserrormessagesexception).